# django unable to implement decorator_from_middleware functionality

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a project where I am trying to write a middleware which when called will verify token from a third party service and check roles stored in that token.
I am able to write and use middleware successfully, but I need to implement it for selected views only, for which I am unable to convert the middleware to decorator using decorator_from_middleware to use only where it is required.

This is the middleware class (with token verification part removed).

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.
        print(f"inside the custom middleware")
        

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

This is how I am trying to use it in a view file.

```
from django.utils.decorators import decorator_from_middleware
from users.middleware import SimpleMiddleware
simple_decorator = decorator_from_middleware(SimpleMiddleware)

class UserPoolInfo(APIView):
    @simple_decorator
    def get(self, request):
        user_manager_object = UserManager()
        user_pool_info = user_manager_object.get_user_pool_info()
        response_data = {
            "status":"Success",
            "statusCode": status.HTTP_200_OK,
            "message":"fetched user pool information",
            "data": user_pool_info
        }
        return Response(response_data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

we are using Django 5.0 with Django Rest Framework.

I have tried following answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61939067/trying-to-figure-out-how-to-use-decorator-from-middleware-functionality) but it does not seem to work.
I have also tried documentation which says that custom middleware should be compatible with old style of middleware which I cannot figure out how to write, as my exposure to django version before 5.0 is non existent.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem raised from your SimpleMiddleware class , because you didn't set a parent class for it, to do so you must import : `from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin`  and than

```
class SimpleMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.
        print(f"inside the custom middleware")
        

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

and change your code like this. After that add your middleware class into MIDDLEWARE settings in you settings.py file to ensure this middleware work, and you don't need these three lines : `from django.utils.decorators import decorator_from_middleware from users.middleware import SimpleMiddleware simple_decorator = decorator_from_middleware(SimpleMiddleware)`. **just one warning: add middleware after all the other middleware**. I suggest you to read this paper about custom middleware : [How to create a custom middleware in django?](https://reintech.io/blog/writing-custom-middleware-class-django#google_vignette)

Comment: I will be trying the approach you suggested, but for the time being we have implemented the middleware from decorator functionality by writing middleware in old middleware style as suggested by django docs. As we only require said middleware to be active on selected routes only.

Comment: OK, test it and if it works, send a comment